# Does below php code has any security risk involved?

Tags: php, security

page1.php

```
<form method="post" action="page2.php">
<textarea name="tryit" cols="!20" rows="10"></textarea>
</form>
```

page 2.php

```
<?php
echo filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'tryit', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
?>
```

I just dont want any user to execute any system code or call any system function.

Thanks

Comment: possibly a better fit for [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is safe in terms of XSS because `filter_input()` with the `FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS` flag will encode the HTML special characters, preventing an XSS vulnerability.

From the [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php):

> **FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS**
>   HTML-escape '"<>& and characters with ASCII value less than 32, optionally strip or encode other special characters.

It's the same as:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['tryit']);
```

If you move the code into another context, for example into an SQL query then it is no longer safe. Special character encoding is specific to preventing XSS.

Comment: IT will not allow any system call to execute right ? 
for example `ls` or exec("ls"); something like that ..

Comment: No system call can be executed with that code. Even without the filter, system calls can't be executed (only Javascript).

Comment: It is safe in terms of XSS *depending on the context it is put out*.

Comment: hope i have no risk involved of cookie stealing here.. document.cookie ?

Comment: @user1940831 the filter will prevent the cookie stealing attack which is XSS.

Comment: also any other javascript harmful code ?
This will be user given input to logged in user..

Comment: Please describe "special effort" ?

Comment: @user1940831 `<script>eval($("#injection").text())</script>` inserted by you

Comment: @user1940831 no Javascript can be executed with the code in question and filter in place.

Comment: @JanDvorak I have no idea what your code will execute ? moreover i dont thing it will be persistent ?

Comment: @JanDvorak obviously if you have some catastrophic vulnerability elsewhere like that then the system isn't safe. You could sit here all night saying, what if you have x, y z. What if you set your root password as `password`?

Comment: well what if user inputs the code mr. JanDvorak has posted ?
what it gonna do ?

Comment: @user1940831 Display the code. You would have to add the code to the page by yourself.

Comment: @user1940831 if the user inputs the code he gave, it will not be executed because as said before, due to the filter and this context, your code is not vulnerabile to XSS.

Comment: @JanDvorak > Trust me, I am really going to make 2 page with same exactly above given code, and no other code in it, not even stylesheet, as i dont need them..

Comment: @user1940831 then no javascript will execute, ever

Comment: Ok.. Thanks . I will update my question with "Considered Safe Code as discussed below involving @JanDvorak @ MrCode, and me :)
Thanks both of you bro :)

Comment: I have added your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php), this replaces all of special html characters: `& ' " <  >` to `&amp; &#039; &quot; &lt;  &gt;`, therafter they will appear as normal characters.

Comment: using filter_input is better than htmlspecialchars i guess ? if i am wrong, please show me the right answer ?

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet will not execute any function of the operating system or any shell command.

`filter_input` will not execute any system function either.

`page2` will only display anything received by the `POST` as text.

The value stored in `$_POST['tryit']` will not be affected. You need to sanitize it separately when you access that variable again (or store its HTML-escaped version somewhere).

`filter_input` is not in common use. You can use specific escaping functions instead.